# jQuery - target previous (identical) divs on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 divs in a row. They all have 1 background on page load. I want to change the BG of the div hovered, and all previous identical divs. I'm not sure how to go about that

```
div { style="background: url(images/red)"}

<div class="myDiv">One</div>
<div class="myDiv">Two<div>
<div class="myDiv">Three</div>
<div class="myDiv">Four</div>
<div class="myDiv">Five</div>
```

so when div THREE above is hovered on, I want divs ONE, TWO, and THREE to have a blue background.

if I did

```
$('.myDiv').hover(function(){
    $(this).prev('.myDiv').css({...});
});
```

It would only affect the first previous one. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Javascript:

```
$('.myDiv').hover(function(){
    $(this).prevAll('.myDiv').andSelf().css({...});
});
```

And you also have a mistake in your markup, the second div isn't closed.:

```
<div class="myDiv">One</div>
<div class="myDiv">Two</div>
<div class="myDiv">Three</div>
<div class="myDiv">Four</div>
<div class="myDiv">Five</div>
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/snynL/

Comment: It was kinda unfair, I just solved this a few days ago implementing a rating system.

Answer (score 2):

kmb385 has the right answer...to expound on his answer, you can unset the backgrounds on mouseout.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/snynL/2/)

```
$('.myDiv').on({
    mouseover: function(){
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().css("background", "red");
    },
    mouseout: function(){
    $('.myDiv').css("background", "");
    }
});
```